# How to save previous password to be able to change current one

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I'm working on an intranet, I fused the creation of an account (through form authentication) with the creation of an Employee - creating an Employee creates an account (simple).

But here's the issue, I wish to make it that when I change my password in the Employee section, it also changes it in the form auth. part.

Here's what I have so far :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Employee objToEdit, FormCollection form)
{
    //string oldpwd = objToEdit.Password;            
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyList = _service.ListCompany();
    ViewBag.CompanyList = CompanyList;

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupervisorList = _service.ListSupervisor();
    ViewBag.SupervisorList = SupervisorList;

    objToEdit.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    objToEdit.CompanyId = int.Parse(form["CompanyId"]);
    objToEdit.Supervisor = form["Supervisor"];

    if (_service.Edit(objToEdit))
    {
        //bool changePasswordSucceeded; // Find a way to store old and new pwd
        //try
        //{
        //    changePasswordSucceeded = WebSecurity.ChangePassword(User.Identity.Name, oldpwd, objToEdit.Password);
        //}
        //catch (Exception)
        //{
        //    changePasswordSucceeded = false;
        //}

        //if (changePasswordSucceeded)
        //{
        //    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = CRAWebSiteMVC.Controllers.AccountController.ManageMessageId.ChangePasswordSuccess });
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The current password is incorrect or the new password is invalid.");
        //}
        return new RedirectResult(Url.Action("Index"));
    }
    return View();
}
```

Everything that is in comment comes from the form authentication Manage function, I wanted to take the old password and change it with the new, but I can't seem to find a way to save the old one.

Tested it with the password written directly in the oldpwd (e.g `oldpwd = "mypwd"`) string and it worked, all I need is a way to save the previous one.

Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to concatenate old pwd with new pwd ?
I mean:

```
oldpwd = "mypwd"."====".oldpwd;
```

With this oldpwd variable will look like this:

```
NEWPASS====OLDPASS
```

Best of luck !

Comment: The issue is that I can't find a way to save oldpwd. With it being equal to `objToEdit.Password` it takes the current (so already changed) passwords value.

Comment: Well. There is one time where you can access the old and the new password no ?

So at this moment, put the new password = oldpassword."====".newpassword;